C# Selenium Proxy Authentication For Firefox
I'm creating an automation program with Selenium Firefox, but I'm having problems adding a proxy to the driver.
Here is the code I used:
lib: SeleniumProxyAuthentication.Firefox 1.0.2, Selenium.Support 4.25.0, Selenium.WebDriver 4.25.0
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using SeleniumProxyAuthentication;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace Main
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static (FirefoxDriver driver, FirefoxDriverService driverService) CreateFirefox()
        {
            try
            {
                FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
                firefoxOptions.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
                firefoxOptions.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("extensions.blocklist.enabled", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("dom.disable_open_during_load", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("app.update.auto", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("extensions.update.enabled", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("app.update.service.enabled", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("app.update.auto", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("app.update.staging", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("app.update.silent", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("extensions.blocklist.enabled", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("media.gmp-manager.cert.requireBuiltIn", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("media.gmp-manager.cert.checkAttributes", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("media.gmp-provider.enabled", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("media.gmp-widevinecdm.enabled", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("media.gmp-widevinecdm.visible", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("media.gmp.trial-create.enabled", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("media.peerconnection.enabled", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.safebrowsing.downloads.remote.enabled", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.safebrowsing.provider.mozilla.gethashURL", "");
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.safebrowsing.provider.mozilla.updateURL", "");
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("app.update.url", "");
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("extensions.systemAddon.update.url", "");
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("media.gmp-manager.url", "");
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("dom.webdriver.enabled", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("webdriver_enable_native_events", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("media.peerconnection.enabled", preferenceValue: false);
                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("media.navigator.permission.disabled", preferenceValue: true);
                firefoxOptions.AddArgument("--width=360");
                firefoxOptions.AddArgument("--height=960");

                firefoxOptions.SetPreference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0");
                firefoxOptions.BrowserExecutableLocation = "Firefox\\App\\Firefox\\firefox.exe";
                FirefoxDriverService firefoxDriverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                firefoxDriverService.BrowserCommunicationPort = FindPort();
                firefoxDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
                FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxDriverService, firefoxOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180.0));

                return (driver, firefoxDriverService);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return (null, null);
        }

        private static int FindPort()
        {
            int port = 0;
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                socket.Bind(localEP);
                localEP = (IPEndPoint)socket.LocalEndPoint;
                port = localEP.Port;
            }
            finally
            {
                socket.Close();
            }
            return port;
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FirefoxDriver driver;
            FirefoxDriverService driverService;
            (driver, driverService) = CreateFirefox();
            driver.AddProxyAuthenticationExtension(new SeleniumProxyAuthentication.Proxy(
                    ProxyProtocols.HTTP,
                    "198.23.239.134:6540:hhsdfhbfs:hdfheryfg"
                    ));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
        }
    }
}

This is the error I get when running the program:
System.MissingMethodException
HResult=0x80131513
Message=Method not found: 'Void OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver.InstallAddOnFromFile(System.String)'.
Source=SeleniumProxyAuthentication
StackTrace:
at SeleniumProxyAuthentication.ProxyAuthentication.AddProxyAuthenticationExtension[T](T browserDriver, Proxy proxy, XpiManifest xpiManifest)
I have also tried a few other ways but when Firefox is opened there will be a dialog box asking to enter the proxy account name and password!
